# Java 1.7 and JSF 1.2 compatibility

Tags: java-7, jsf-1.2, ibm-was

I'm working to upgrade JDK for a Web app from 1.4 to 1.7 and Websphere Application server 6.1 to 8.5 (WAS 6.1 to 8.5).

The application is built using JSF 1.2. My question is does JSF 1.2 is compatible with Java 1.7 or does it require to upgrade JSF 1.2 to 2.0? Any pointers in this relation is most valuable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

JSF 1.2 is compitible with java 1.6.
You can change your version of java in a 
Project>Build Path>Configure then select Java to change it

If you want to use java 7, then you need to move on JSF 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with JSF 1.2 and JDK > 7.0.21
I do not remember the exact cause, but that was a known issue and never fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSF 1.2 with WAS 8.5, you will need to change default JSF via application options `Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications > application_name > JSP and JSF options` and switch to `Sun Reference Implementation 1.2`.

For more details see [Configuring JavaServer Faces implementation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F2-13-2-32-0-2-3&lang=en)